# Cosa significa "punta d'assaggio"?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *L'isola*, di Giani Stuparich, ho letto:

> – Quando sarai guarito... – la menzogna tremò sulle labbra del figlio; ma egli la sentì necessaria e crudele come una **punta d'assaggio**. Era quello il momento di tentar di penetrare nella coscienza di suo padre. Lo osservava e vide che un lievissimo rossore gli si diffondeva per le guance, sotto la pelle scialba.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "punta d'assaggio" in questo passaggio? Ho cercato i termini "punta" e "assaggio" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire cos'è una "punta d'assaggio".

**Aggiornamento:**

Ho trovato l'espressione "punta d'assaggio" in atri documenti:

- http://www.farnesina.ipzs.it/series/NONA%20SERIE/volumi/VOLUME%20VIII/full
- http://www.intravino.com/primo-piano/lettera-a-un-wine-blogger-mai-nato/
- http://www.bwined.it/il-bianco-di-baal-e-i-crudi-di-pesce/
- https://books.google.es/books?id=wPc-AQAAMAAJ&q=%22punta+d%27assaggio%22&dq=%22punta+d%27assaggio%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-yo20qZPiAhVozoUKHVQqBaQQ6AEIETAB
- http://www.lincei.it/pubblicazioni/rendicontiFMN/rol/pdf/S5V24T1A1915P48_54.pdf

(i due ultimi sono lo stesso documento in due formati diversi).

Comment: Si riferisce sicuramente ad un oggetto acuminato, che per metafora "penetra" nella coscienza del personaggio, infierendo. È possibile che si riferisca ad un coltello tipo questo: http://www.coltelleriart.com/925-large_default_2x/bharbjt-coltello-per-assaggi-punta-a-forchetta-cm-16.jpg

Comment: Potrebbe riferirsi alla punta che si infila nel prosciutto per sentire il sapore dell'interno. http://www.sanfrancescospa.it/testimonial/prosciutto-osso-di-cavallo/

Comment: Come si conciliano queste ipotesi con gli aggettivi "necessaria" e "crudele"?

Comment: "Necessario" secondo il dizionario Treccani deriva da _ne_ e _cedere_ ossia "da cui non c’è modo di ritirarsi"; quindi potrebbe in questo contesto essere utilizzato come sinonimo di "implacabile", "inesorabile".

Answer (score 1):

Sicuramente il brano si riferisce ad un oggetto con una punta aguzza, come potrebbe essere ad esempio un coltello; Sono del parere che il commento di @egreg sia corretto, e che si tratti della punta che si infila nel prosciutto per saggiarlo (http://www.sanfrancescospa.it/testimonial/prosciutto-osso-di-cavallo/). Nel contesto, significa che la menzogna è "penetrata" nell'interlocutore in modo assai doloroso, come una stilettata.

L'aggettivo "Necessario" secondo il dizionario Treccani deriva da *ne* e *cedere* ossia "da cui non c’è modo di ritirarsi"; quindi potrebbe in questo contesto essere utilizzato come sinonimo di "implacabile", "inesorabile"; "crudele" è un'aggettivo che si adatta bene a descrivere il dolore provocato da un oggetto acuminato.